# How does Google Drive API support Content-Range for download requests?

Tags: google-drive-api

How does Google Drive API support for get Content-Range requests?
There are limits are App Engine get request sizes. Please support range requests so that large file sizes can be read.

Comment: This is a totally legitimate question. Please re-read. I have edited it to make it more obvious for you Pere and Casper to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You can provide the Range: header, for example:

```
Range: bytes=5-12
```

To download only the required bytes, in this case 5-12. Please see [additional documentation about downloads](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_documents_and_files).