# Does the Google Drive API support Content-Range for Uploads?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Similar to this question: [How does Google Drive API support Content-Range for download requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303126/how-does-google-drive-api-support-content-range-for-download-requests)

but for **uploads**. Does the Drive/Docs API let you set a range if you want to update some bytes in an existing file?

Answer (score 2):

This depends what you are trying to do.

You can't upload a few bytes to an existing file in a random access way. The API does, however, support the [resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/resumable_upload) protocol so that you can upload large files in chunks. This is fault tolerant per chunk, and uploads can be restarted for any reason if there is a failure.

Comment: Thanks, Ali. 

I'm looking for random access, setting the write pointer withing a file, not resumable upload.

It would be a very useful feature to request. Why? Many times you only need to change a small part of the file on Google Drive. This saves time and bandwidth. Most other cloud storage providers have this function.

Comment: Understood, I agree this would be a great feature.